# Minimal steps to allow a Grails 4 application to run under Jetty (9+)?

Tags: grails, jetty

What are the minimum changes required to a blank-slate Grails 4 application, for it to successfully run under Jetty 9+ as a `.war` archive?

If I do a naive deployment of a `.war`, it shows up as static content (a directory listing) under Jetty. Perhaps this is something to do with a missing `web.xml`, which Grails hasn't used for some time?

Put another way: how do I bridge the gap between modern Grails and what Jetty is expecting?

Comment: Are you wanting to deploy a `.war` file to a Jetty instance, or are you wanting to use an embedded Jetty?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown : The former - deploying a `.war` file to an existing Jetty instance. I will try Puneet Behl's answer when I'm back in front of my development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run Grails web application WAR with Jetty, please update the following dependency as:

```
// compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
```

Also, you may need to also update the Jetty version via SpringBoot BOM as:

```
ext['jetty.version'] = 9.4.36.v20210114
```

Here is an [example Grails 4 application](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-jetty-example) which uses Jetty instead of Tomcat.

Comment: Using the `.war` file generated via `gradle bootWar`, it still only shows up as a static directory listing under my Jetty (9.4.36) instance (also tried renaming it `ROOT.war` as is going on with the provided example)

Running it standalone (`java -jar grails-jetty-example-0.1.war`) works as expected ... but that's not what I'm attempting to do - I want to run it under an existing Jetty server.

Is there anything 'extra' going on in that docker image that could explain my different experience? I'm still only getting a static directory listing, instead of the Grails app as expected.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/rtVbOxi.png) is what I see with every `.war` I've attempted generating from Grails 4.

Comment: No, I think there must be some configuration problem with your Jetty instance. You may want to disable `dirAllowed` in web.xml.

Comment: Using the demo-base provided with Jetty 9 worked fine, so it was indeed a configuration issue (though I haven't yet gone deeper to find out exactly what it was). Marked as 'answered', thanks!